# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have a simple app to add data into table,

[image]

the + button gives this (showing the form to add and normally to edit):

[image]

my code working well for adding and deletin, but when i want to edit un element i have this problem :

```
TablesComponent.html:72 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
```

if the form is not viewed before, i know where is my error but i can not see how to handle it:

```
<form style="width:100%" *ngIf="showForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddLine(bapF)" #bapF="ngForm">
```

in the function on edit button, i show the form first and after i set its values to the selected element (the code is going to set the form values before that the form is added to the DOM):

```
updateEltBap (eltIndex: number, bapElt: Bap) {
this.showForm = true;
this.editMode = true;
this.bapEditedElt = this.bapTable[eltIndex];
this.bapF.setValue({cBap: this.bapEditedElt.code_bap, nBap: this.bapEditedElt.nom_bap});
```

}

thanks for your help

Comment: Please post your whole TS code, this will be easier.

Comment: probably because your object is not initialized (ngModel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `#bapF="ngForm"` in your template means that you can use `bapF` in that template, but it does not make it automatically accessible from the component's code.

Try adding this to your component

```
@ViewChild('bapF') bapF;
```